# How to update TextView of custom ArrayAdapter on the basis of EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ArrayAdapter which is a horizontal LinearLayout containing 02 EditText fields and 01 TextView.....all are set to take/show numberDecimals.

All I want is that whenever a number is input in any of the EditText fields, the product of the two numbers (EditText 1 & EditText 2) is shown in TextView.

I've tried both OnFocusChangedListener and TextChangedListener but the TextView doesnt get updated during live entries. It doesnt show anything.

I'm new to programming, so cant find any other solution for that. 
Thanks in advance!

Below is the Adapter code:

```
TextView labelView;
EditText ratioView;
EditText rateView;
TextView avgView;


public FibresAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Fibres> fibresList) {
    super(context, 0, fibresList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    final Fibres currentFibre = getItem(position);

    labelView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    labelView.setText(currentFibre.fibreLabel);

    ratioView = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(ratio);
    rateView = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    avgView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avg);

    ratioView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                currentFibre.fibreRatio = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                avgView.setText("Testing");
            } else {
                currentFibre.fibreRatio = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    rateView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                currentFibre.fibreRate = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                avgView.setText("Testing");
            } else {
                currentFibre.fibreRate = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Below is the code for Activity:

```
double totalAvg;
double totalRatio;

TextView totalAvgView;
TextView totalRatioView;

static ArrayList<Fibres> fibres;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fibres_list);

    fibres = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = 0;

    while (x < Fibres.fibCatArray.length) {
        fibres.add(new Fibres(Fibres.fibCatArray[x]));
        x++;
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    FibresAdapter adapter = new FibresAdapter(this, fibres);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    totalRatioView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_ratio);
    totalAvgView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_avg);

}

public void displayTotals() {
    totalRatio = 0;
    totalAvg = 0;

    for (Fibres materials : fibres) {
        totalRatio += materials.fibreRatio;
        totalAvg += (materials.fibreRatio / 100 * materials.fibreRate);
    }
    totalRatioView.setText(totalRatio + "");
    totalAvgView.setText(totalAvg + "");

}

public boolean validateData() {
    if (totalRatio != 100) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Total should be 100%!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    for (Fibres materials : fibres) {
        if (materials.fibreRatio > 1 && materials.fibreRate <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter both Ratio & Rate!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter add addTextChangedListener to both EditText and use textView.setText() inside that. Something like this.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
        textView.setText("");
   }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've done it but still nothing is shown in textView.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan update your question with your adapter and activity/fragment code

Comment: I've updated the question with relevant codes. What I've noticed is that the text now appears in the textview but at wrong places. pl suggest a solution.